# Docker image in repo, using cache

Tags: python, docker, azure-pipelines

I built a simple python package using poetry. I have a repository and my test are running in a Docker container, I published a Docker image in the same repo. I have an Azure pipeline and when I commit I use cache to build the Docker image. I have the following problem, in the image I have to build my python package, so if the pyproject has changed, for example, when I add a new library, the image will execute

```
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./

RUN poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi
```

Is there a more efficient way to use the cache? in the sense that if I add or delete a library, then only build/delete the new one and all those that depend on it.

Another problem in the way i'm building the image is that if my pyproject change because a new version of my package, then the installation will be executed.

Comment: I have separated the installation of dependences from the installation of my own package

Comment: Hi @Andrex How was it going with this case, Was below answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 1):

It seems impossible to only build/delete the new library from the cache. since it is the default behavior that the cached image will be invalidated if the contents of the files from Add and Copy instructions. And docker will run all the instructions in order in dockerfile to generate a new image.

Check the **Leverage build cache** section in [this document](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) to learn more about how docker pick up a cached image and determine whether to create a new image.